# CSS code in HTML and main.css

Tags: html, css

Any ideas why this CSS code doesn't work when I put it inside main.css file?
I'm trying to make fullscreen background.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
 <style>
  .bg {
      background-image: url("nuotraukos/bg.png");
      min-height:100%;
      min-width: 100%;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Providing a code linking to local files won't work here as a snippet.

Comment: I know that code won't work as a snippet. Main question is why this css code does only work between HTML style tags, but it doesn't work in main.css file even tho it has link to it.

Comment: Are you getting a 404 when trying to access ''nuotraukos/bg.png''? My guess is that the path is incorrect because it is reading it from the CSS/ directory.

Comment: @JonathanKempf, thank you! I forgot that my css file is in a different directory. I'm so oblivious today... :D Thank you once more! :)

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing seems to be wrong with your `<link>`.
Check if the file really exists and if the `html` page is in the same directory as the `CSS` folder. Otherwise the file path is wrong.

If the image is not displaying, it's probably because it's not in the same path as the `.css`, so you should change the link too.

Let's suppose your image is one folder up the css file. Then you should change the url to this:

```
url("../nuotraukos/bg.png");
```

Also it's not a good practice to use a div to set a background, so instead of using a div to set a background, set a background to the `<body>` and stretch it.

```css
body {
   background-image: url("http://images.alphacoders.com/538/53823.jpg");
   background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<head>

</head>
<body>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would help if you change the path when you place main.css in the CSS folder?

```
background-image: url("../nuotraukos/bg.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width intial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta https-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge"/>
    <title>First Website</title>
    <link rel="style-sheet" href="css/reset.css"
    <link rel="style-sheet" href="css/main.css"
</head>
<body>
<div id="Home">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="background-image">
        <div class="content-area">
            <div class="user-image">
                <div class="circle">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Editing help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) are here. I also deleted 75 blank lines from your answer. Please try not to do that again...

Comment: Although, to be honest, blank lines are sometimes a great way to keep your code organised and in groups :)